# Error regarding table tag

Tags: html, html-table, tags

I'm coding a website, and i've run into a problem. I'm pretty sure i've opened and closed a table correctly, but i get an error from Adobe Dreamweaver CC saying i haven't. The specific error messages i get are as follows:

1. (on line 153): "Tag must be paired, missing: [], start tag matched failed [] on line 112."
2. (on line 174): "Tag must be paired, no start tag: []"
3. (on line 191]: "Tag must be paired, missing: [], start tag matched failed [] on line 156."
4. (on line 193): "Tag must be paired, no start tag: []"

Here's my source code (Ignore the plain text, i'm coding a Norwegian website):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nb">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
<title>Bergen Eiendom</title>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid"> 
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myInverseNavbar2" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">EFA Eiendom</a> </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myInverseNavbar2">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="index.html">Hjem</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">Om oss</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Bank</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ENG/NO</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true">Adresser <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Adresse 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Adresse 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Adresse 3</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Noe annet?</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse --> 
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid --> 
</nav>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 hidden-xs">
        <div id="carousel-299058" class="carousel slide">
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel-299058" data-slide-to="0" class=""> </li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-299058" data-slide-to="1" class="active"> </li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-299058" data-slide-to="2" class=""> </li>
          </ol>
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item"> <img class="img-responsive" src="imagescomputer-networking-1920x500.jpg" alt="thumb">
              <div class="carousel-caption"> Beskrivelse av bilde. Kanskje bilde av en av leilighetene? </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item active"> <img class="img-responsive" src="images/growth-homeslider-jumpstart-1920x500.jpg" alt="thumb">
              <div class="carousel-caption"> Et annet bilde med beskrivelse. </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item"> <img class="img-responsive" src="images/last ned.jpg" alt="thumb">
              <div class="carousel-caption"> Et tredje bilde med beskrivelse </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-299058" data-slide="prev"><span class="icon-prev"></span></a> <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-299058" data-slide="next"><span class="icon-next"></span></a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
  </div>
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
        <div class="media-object-default">
          <div class="media">
            <div class="media-left"> <a href="#"> <img class="media-object img-circle" src="images/100X100.gif" alt="placeholder image"> </a> </div>
            <div class="media-body">
              <h4 class="media-heading">Adresse 1</h4>
              Dette er tekst.Dette er tekst.Dette er tekst.Dette er tekst.Dette er tekst.Dette er tekst.Dette er tekst.Dette er tekst.Dette er tekst.Dette er tekst.Dette er tekst.Dette er tekst.</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
        <div class="media">
          <div class="media-left"> <a href="#"> <img class="media-object img-circle" src="images/100X100.gif" alt="placeholder image"></a></div>
          <div class="media-body">
            <h4 class="media-heading">Adresse 2</h4>
            Dette er tekst.Dette er tekst.Dette er tekst.Dette er tekst.Dette er tekst.Dette er tekst.Dette er tekst.Dette er tekst.Dette er tekst.Dette er tekst.Dette er tekst.Dette er tekst.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
        <div class="media">
          <div class="media-left"> <a href="#"> <img class="media-object img-circle" src="images/100X100.gif" alt="placeholder image"></a></div>
          <div class="media-body">
            <h4 class="media-heading">Adresse 3</h4>
           Dette er tekst.Dette er tekst.Dette er tekst.Dette er tekst.Dette er tekst.Dette er tekst.Dette er tekst.Dette er tekst.Dette er tekst.Dette er tekst.Dette er tekst.Dette er tekst.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<hr>

<div class="containerapcontact">

    <div class="aligntoright">
     <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-lg-offset-0">
<table>
       <tr>
         <div class="well">
        <h3 class="text-center">Finn et bosted</h3>
        <form class="form-horizontal">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="location1" class="control-label">Adresse</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="" id="location1">
              <option value="">Alle adresser</option>
              <option value="">Adresse 1</option>
              <option value="">Adresse 2</option>
              <option value="">Adresse 3</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="type1" class="control-label">Type</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="" id="type1">
              <option value="">Hvilket som helst bosted</option>
              <option value="">Liten leilighet</option>
              <option value="">Stor leilighet</option>
              <option value="">Kollektiv</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="pricefrom" class="control-label">Pris fra</label>
            <div class="input-group">
              <div class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">kr</div>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pricefrom" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="priceto" class="control-label">Pris til</label>
            <div class="input-group">
              <div class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">kr</div>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="priceto" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
            </div>
          </div>
          <p class="text-center"><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" role="button">Søk </a></p>
        </form>
         </div>     
      </tr>
         </div> 

      <!--Code for embedded Google Map-->
       <tr>
<script>
      function initMap() {
        var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 4,
          center: uluru
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: uluru,
          map: map
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&callback=initMap">
    </script>
     <!--End of code for embedded Google Map-->
        </table>
      <hr>
      <h3 class="text-center">Kontaktpersoner</h3>
      <div class="media-object-default">
        <div class="media">
          <div class="media-left"> <a href="#"> <img class="media-object img-rounded" src="images/64X64.gif" alt="placeholder image"> </a> </div>
          <div class="media-body">
            <h4 class="media-heading">Kontaktperson 1</h4>
            <abbr title="Phone">tlf:</abbr> +47 123 456 78 <a href="mailto:#">kontakt1@hotmail.com</a> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="media">
          <div class="media-left"> <a href="#"> <img class="media-object img-rounded" src="images/64X64.gif" alt="placeholder image"> </a> </div>
          <div class="media-body">
            <h4 class="media-heading">Kontaktperson 2</h4>
            <abbr title="Phone">tlf:</abbr> +47 456 234 78 <a href="mailto:#">kontakt2@hotmail.com</a> </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    </tr>
    </div>
<hr>

<footer class="text-center">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <p>Copyright/Rights served deklarasjon</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) --> 
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script> 
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed --> 
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have any actual columns in  your `<tr>` tags TR = Table Row.

The HTML table structure is this:

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>Column 1</th>
<th>Column 2</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Col 1: Row1</td>
<td>Col 2: Row1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Co1:Row2</td>
<td>Col2:Row2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Aha, gotcha. Thank you very much!